# How to use Mysql to get a list of locations where an id has been?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the columns id and location. The table is of location data being pinged, and I want to get output containing the id, the number of distinct locations that id shows up in, as well as well as a list of the locations that id has been to.

this is what I am trying -

```
select prim.id, count(distinct(location)), 
 (select location 
  from dbo.Events_compiled 
  where id = prim.id)
from dbo.Events_compiled as prim 
group by prim.id 
order by count(distinct(location)) desc;
```

I am getting this error -
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

How can I get the output I am looking for?

Answer (score 0):

There is a function to do this-- called GROUP_CONCAT

```
SELECT ID, count(distinct locaiton) as cnt,
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT location ORDER BY location SEPARATOR ',') as list
FROM dbo.events_compiled
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY count(distinct(location)) desc;
```

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.

Comment: I am getting the above error when i run that

Comment: @user1640555533423.  Are you running some very old MySQL version? (The above syntax has been there for ages.)

Comment: maybe you have a typo -- is your code exactly as above?